# Heroku + Django : Restarting a dyno every 15 min

Tags: django, heroku

I have a Django website hosted on Heroku.
I need to restart 1 dyno "clock" (my crontab APScheduler) every 15 minutes.

Through Heroku CLI, this can be done through the command line:

```
heroku dyno:restart clock.1
```

But I can't seem to automate it from within the Django app.

I've tried to use my crontab APScheduler to restart itself:

1. creating a Management command called **restart_clock**

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Restarting dyno"
    
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        os.system('heroku dyno:restart clock.1')
```

==> If I run manually `python manage.py restart_clock`, **it works**

2. running it as a crontab inside the app, hosted on Heroku, through the APScheduler

```
@sched.scheduled_job('cron',minute="*/10")
def restart():
    os.system('python manage.py restart_clock')

sched.start()
```

But then, I get a message error
`sh: 1: heroku: not found`

It feels like Django can't run Heroku CLI commands as cronjobs...
Is there a way to run a Heroku CLI command line every 15 minutes ?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you and answer your question: [How to setup a cron job in Django](https://gutsytechster.wordpress.com/2019/06/24/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-django/)

Comment: Thanks. I've already set up a crontab but it's not working : let me edit my post